# How to sort a playlist in iTunes 12.2.1.6

Tags: itunes, playlist

[image: screenshot]

Ever since the last iTunes update (12.2.1.6), there's a new way of displaying playlists, where the songs are twice the size vertically, and I can't find any column headers to sort the playlist by. I want to sort the playlist by Year. It might be really simple but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

For ver 12.4.1.6 the pulldown on the right is gone.  In the menu bar click View > View As > Songs

Answer (score 0):

Switch your view to Songs, rather than Playlist, top right.

[image]